# Configure two git remote repositories to two corresponding local branches

Tags: git, github

Rephrasing the question : how to configure a remote git repository as new branch of an existing local repository whose single branch is already linked to a different remote repository.

I have two git repositories(projects) hosted on two different sites (github and an intranet site).

They are similar to each other since they started from the same base folder. I want to combine these two projects into one single git project such that

- local branch "master" points to github repo's "master" branch
- local branch "intranet_branch" points to intranet site repo's "master" branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a previous Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/10548919) I figured out a way to achieve this as [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories/10548919#comment39886785_10548919)

- cd to local folder linked to github repo

  ```
  cd ~/projects/prj_a
  ```
- update .git/config to restrict branch mapping such that local "master" branch points to github's "master" branch

  ```
  [remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:user/prj_a.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
  ```
- Add new git remote

  ```
  git remote add intranet git@intranet_server:user/intranet_project.git
  ```
- update .git/config such that new git remote is fetched into new remote-branch

  ```
  [remote "intranet"]
  url = git@intranet_server:user/intranet_project.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/intranet/intranet_branch
  ```
- Fetch branches from new remote repo

  ```
  git fetch intranet
  ```
- checkout new remote's branch into a new local branch. This will also switch to new branch.

  ```
  git checkout -b intranet_branch intranet/intranet_branch
  ```
- merge master branch which is pointing to github

  ```
  git merge master
  ```
- Resolve merge conflicts and commit
- push from intranet_branch to intranet_repo's master branch

  ```
  git push intranet intranet_branch
  ```

Test everything once more

```
    $ git checkout master
      Switched to branch 'master'
      Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
    $ git pull origin master
      ....
      * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
      Already up-to-date.
    $ git push origin master
      Everything up-to-date
    $ git checkout intranet_branch 
      Switched to branch 'intranet_branch'
      Your branch is up-to-date with 'intranet/intranet_branch'.
    $ git pull intranet intranet_branch 
      ...
      * branch           intranet_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
      Already up-to-date.
    $ git push intranet intranet_branch 
      Everything up-to-date
```